# Formula to produce a liner result between 0 and 50000

Tags: sequences-and-series

Not sure if this is right place to ask but I would like a formula that will convert a given value a result based on a scale up to 50000.

For example at `0` the result is `50`, at `50000` the result is `5`. at `25000` the result should be `22.50` or there about's.

Comment: Your question is not really clear. Also, if what you want is a formula that approximates a series based on certain values, you should give more values (and if possible consecutive indexes)

Answer (score 1):

The [two-point form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation#Two-point_form) of a linear equation is given by
$$
y - y_1 = \frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1} (x - x_1).
$$
In your case, $(x_1,y_1)=(0,50)$ and $(x_2,y_2)=(50000,5)$.